# AWS Lambda sends 502 Bad Gateway when I try to login from the frontend. But when I send incorrect login details, I get a 401

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, fastapi

I'm deploying a note management service. It's nothing special, the backend was written in FastAPI, the frontend in React, and the database is PostgreSQL. I decided the best thing for such a stack is to use AWS. I created an aws lambda for the backend and put the frontend in an S3 Bucket, then tied it all together.

Everything works, but when I try to log in to the user account, I get something strange. If I enter incorrect data, (for example, wrong login) I get 401 Unauthorized, which is normal. But when I enter the correct data, I get 502 Bad Gateway. I really don't understand what the problem could be, because I ran all this locally, with a connection to AWS RDS and everything worked. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

At first I thought it was a front-end issue, but after testing the API with Postman, I realized that it wasn't. Then I thought the problem was in the database. After running everything locally, but leaving the database in AWS RDS, everything worked. So I think the problem is with AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 6):

Since no one has answered, I'll answer it myself =)

The whole problem is in the timeout. By default, aws lambda has a timeout of 3 seconds. Since I do not exceed the timeout, I get 502 Bad Gateway. To solve this problem, just increase the timeout. Or you can choose a region that is closer to you, but it depends on your location.

To increase the timeout:

1. Go to your lambda
2. Then go to "**configurations**" and select "**general configurations**"
3. Click "**edit**", after which you can change the timeout)

I hope this will help you)